# Low Search: Search by Postal code, populate latitude, longitude automatically

Tags: low-search

I'm a little lost here. I have the following situation:

1. I have channel entries (properties) which are geocoded (latitude, longitude)
2. I'm trying to use Low Search to look for properties and have them sorted by distance from preferred location / address

Problem: How do I tell Low Search which geocode the address (City or Street or Postal Code) the user is searching for has?

Here's the detail page of Low Search:
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#distance

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Search's Distance filter takes lat/long values as from and to values to calculate the distances per entry. If you want to use addresses, it's up to you to transform that into lat/long values, before sending that data off to Low Search.

[This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20postcode%20to%20latitude%20longitude) will give you a [nice start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98449/how-to-convert-an-address-to-a-latitude-longitude).

Comment: This http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/geotagger might come in handy.